# does git retain some knowledge of what time the commit was made

Tags: git, bash, timestamp

As I understand it, commits that don't show up in `git log` can still exist in the repository. I've checked this myself, by doing `git show id-of-squashed-commit`

My question is, does git store some knowledge of what time the commit was made?

Use case: Say you hired a coder to work on the weekdays, but suspect all the work gets done in the weekends. The coder squashes commits before push to GitHub. But can those hidden commits contain some timing information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: each commit has *two* time stamps attached, the "author" timestamp and the "committer" timestamp.

There are numerous pitfalls with trying to use these, though:

- They're under control of the author/committer.
- They're subject to erroneous computer clocks.
- They may be difficult to interpret (they have time zone offsets).
- Even if they're accurate, you must *have* the commit objects.

Because Git is distributed, and committers can commit within their own repositories, they can make a series of commits, then `git squash` the series of commits to make a new commit, then `git push` *only* the new commit.  In this case you don't *have* the original commits anywhere: they are only in the committer's repository, not on GitHub and not in your clone either.